# Send OAuth access_token with redirect uri fragment

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) that communicates with my REST backend.
Additionally to email/password authentication, I want to add social logins like Google and Facebook. Therefore I implemented the authorization code flow as seen in the following picture. The flow cannot be done using XHR requests, so we have to redirect the user.

[image]

The last step is the one I am struggling with. The only way to pass my_api_access_token to the user is as (EDIT: fragment not parameter) for the redirect uri. I am afraid that this is not good practice but I have not much experience with OAuth.

The other solution I am thinking about is the implicit flow. Here we would get an access_token directly and an XHR request to my API would work.
This feels bit less secure and the implicit flow is not supported by every major company (e.g. Github OAuth).

[image]

Could anyone with more experience point me in the right direction of where to go from here?
I would appreciate any discussion.

Comment: Google isnt going to let you add parameters to the redirect uri.   Im not exactly sure what it is you are trying to do but i think you are over thinking it some how.   Im not exactly sure what your question is either.

Comment: @DaImTo with authorization code flow, I would not add parameters to the google redirect uri but to the redirection in the last step to the frontend from MY backend server. What I just saw is that google seems to pass the access_token in implicit flow as redirect uri parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution involves the following steps:

- SPA uses a client side security library to manage sign in via Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- SPA redirects to a Cloud Authorization Server, not an API
- Authorization Server can redirect further to Google or Facebook
- SPA receives an authorization code and swaps it for an access token via an HTTP POST
- SPA sends access tokens to the API
- API validates access tokens

To understand the high level behaviour, maybe see my [Messages Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/), and have a look at my [Initial Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/).

I would focus first on the default login and connecting the SPA, API and Authorization Server. You can then add support for federation to Google / Facebook later, without changing any code in your SPA or API.